# ¿Cómo llamar funciones de un servicio Go a otro?

Tags: go

Lo que me sucede es que quiero separar mis servicios Go, pero no se como puedo llamar a una función desde mi `main.go`...

Acá les dejo mi archivo `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    log.Println(" Inicio en main de interfaz.go")

    http.HandleFunc("/enviarmovimientosFin700Masivo", enviarmovimientosFin700Masivo)
    http.HandleFunc("/dispensacionRecetalegado", dispensacionRecetalegado)
    http.HandleFunc("/listarmovimientointerfaz", ListarMovimientoInterfaz)
    http.HandleFunc("/enviacargossisalud", enviacargossisalud)
    http.HandleFunc("/listarmovimientointerfazbodegas", listarmovimientointerfazbodegas)
    http.HandleFunc("/wsLogIntegraPedido", wsLogIntegraPedido)
    http.HandleFunc("/consultaCuenta", consultaCuenta)
    http.HandleFunc("/consultaCargoCuenta", consultaCargoCuenta)
    /*mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/login", authentication.Login)
    mux.HandleFunc("/validate", authentication.ValidateToken)*/
    //http.HandleFunc("/validausuario", validausuario)

    http.HandleFunc("/hi", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi")
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8094", nil))

}
```

Acá el servicio con la función q quiero llamar que se llama `serviceEnvmovFin700.go`:

```
package Services

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    database "pkg_conexion"
)
....
func enviarmovimientosFin700Masivo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("******")
    enableCors(&w)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var xml_llamada Envelope_llamado
    // Read body
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error()
......
```

Por favor si alguien sabe como seria de gran ayuda...

Comment: Podrías por favor añadir correctamente los ejemplos de código con las ```

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes a la hora de exportar las funciones de un archivo go, si ves en la documentacion oficial de como [exportar identificadores](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) te explican como puedes realizarlo, es tan simple como poner la primera letra de la función en Mayúscula, de esta forma serán vista fuera del paquete y podrás importarlas/usarlas en tu `main.go`.

Espero que esto sea de tu ayuda, cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar.

Un saludo